# Compiler error "Incompatible types" on byte literal

Tags: java, byte, arrays, bit

I have seen many cases where a byte is declared but where the value from a method like
**intToByte** or **StringToByte** is casted to a byte because the programmer is provideing i.e. a **hexadecimal**- value, an **Integer**- or a **String**-value.

I am trying to assign an actual byte value to the variable without any casting or methods to parse, like so:

```
public class ByteTest   {
      /**
       * This array will be used to hold three characters, together forming a string.
       */
      private static byte[] string;

      /**
       * The main method of the program, where the byte-array is coming to use.
       */
      public static void main(String args[])    {
            //Construct the array with a limit to three bytes.
            string = new byte[3];

            /*
             * Fill the three bytes with the binary values to create "O", "l" and "e".
             */
            string[0] = 01001111;
            string[1] = 01101100;
            string[2] = 01100101;

            //Print out "Ole".
            System.out.println(string[0] + string[1] + string[2]);
      }
}
```

But I get the following error in the compiler:

```
java\ByteTest.java:8: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
                   string[0] = 01001111;
                               ^

java\ByteTest.java:9: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
                       string[1] = 01101100;
                                   ^

java\ByteTest.java:10: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
                       string[2] = 01100101;
                                   ^
```

Appearently, what I think of as eight bits, the compiler thinks of as eight integers.
Is there any other solution to this, where I can provide actually bits directly to the variables/array?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html

Comment: also, `//Print out "Ole".` no. It will print 288. (or possibly 32)

Comment: Strongly recommend not to use the name `string` for that variable. (1) Too similar to the class java.lang.String, (2) variable is not holding a String, so name is misleading. `byteArray` would make more sense.

Comment: So you have a `byte` array that you call _string_ and you're trying to drop large octal values into it?

Comment: It prints out 288, I wonder why.
The three letter "O", "l" and "e" shall have each their binary value, which I got from an ASCII <> binary converter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indicate binary

```
string[0] = 0b01001111;
string[1] = 0b01101100;
string[2] = 0b01100101;
```

This reminds me of the joke: there are 10 kinds of programmers: those that understand binary and those that do not.

As bytes are signed there still is a problem with `0b1xxxxxxx` which would need to be a negative number. In that case use the following trick:

```
string[2] = 0b11100101 - 256;
string[2] = (byte) 0b11100101; // Or simply cast the int range value.
```

Also binary is ideal for an underscore usage:

```
string[2] = 0b0110_0101; // 0x65
```

And is commented by @BackSlash: bytes are binary data. To interprete them as text they have to be associated with some Charset/encoding.

```
String s = new String(string, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
System.out.println(s);
```

This converts the bytes, interpreting them as ASCII to the Unicode that String uses (to combine all scripts of the world).

Comment: Also, OP needs to convert to char before printing, otherwise he will get the sum of the three bytes as output (288 instead of "Ole")

Comment: All ascii characters are between 0 and 127. I can't see that subtracting 256 is better/clearer than a cast `(byte)`

Comment: @BackSlash did oversee that one; added to the answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey that was more to demonstrate that the compiler checks the range of values. A cast would do for 789 too. But you are right, a byte cast is what one should use; I never did - 256.

Comment: @JoopEggen If you wanted to support 0 to 255 or -128 to 127, the `ISO_8859_1` character encoding would be a better choice (and little downside)

Comment: @PeterLawrey thanks, ISO_8859_1 aka Latin-1 would enable  `Olé` with accent é = 0xe9 = 0b1110_1001.

Answer (score 0):

Adding 0 in front of constant number ( like 01101100 )  is interpreted as octal value

Answer (score 0):

What do you need to do to fix this?

The simplest solution which will use the least memory (code and data) is also the simplest.

```
private static final String string = "Ole";

System.out.println(string);
```

otherwise you can do this

```
private static final char[] chars = { 
        (char) 0b01001111, 
        (char) 0b01101100, 
        (char) 0b01100101 };

String s = new String(chars);
System.out.println(s);
```

Note: characters in Java are 16-bit unsigned `char`, not 8 bit `byte`

To get an idea of why the class file is bigger you can dump the class file with

```
java -c -v -cp target/classes mypackage.MyClass
```

---

To start with `01001111` is in octal, not binary. To write a binary number, you need `0b01001111`

Numbers don't "remember" how many leading zeros you gave it, and generally speaking, leading zeros are dropped when printed.

The default format for a number is decimal, not binary.

When you add two, or three numbers, you get another number.  Assuming you got this to compile it would print something like

288

or whatever the sum of the values are.

BTW it is really confusing to name an `int` called "string" because this could be assumed to be a `String`

Comment: I am trying to create some sort of a String with only space enough for these three characters.

Comment: @OleKristianMøller-Hansen funny story, did you know the most efficient way to store a `byte[]` in code Java is as a `String` (unless you have lots of Strings generated at runtime).  I haven't seen someone try to store a String as a byte[] before. Can you explain why you are trying to do this?

Comment: Hmm, how is that the case? Will not a String-declaration crate a signed String with a set amount of bits, where as I am trying to store only three characters, only leads to a huge amount of excessive bits?

Comment: @OleKristianMøller-Hansen You haven't counted all the bytes of byte code you are using to create your byte[].  Try seeing how big the class file is if you create a simple `String` as a string and you will see it is much *smaller*

Answer (score 0):

Assign Actual value :-

```
String a ="100101";
System.out.println(""+a);
Output :- 100101
```

Binary to integer conversion and then assign value to string variable :-

```
String a=""+0b100101
System.out.println(""+a);
Output: 37
```